# Vuejs 2 assign data to variable with event received data from eventbus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a small client-side Vuejs application and have a bit of trouble with assigning data to a variable. In a login component I am emitting user data with an eventBus, and in an index component I receive the data from the eventbus within the `mounted: function ()`. I have no trouble with receiving the data, but what I would like to do is assign this received data to the `currentUser` variable. This is what I have in the `index component`:

```
mounted: function () {
    eventBus.$on('thisEvent', function (userObject) {
        console.log('event received!', userObject)
        this.currentUser = userObject.user
        console.log('The user: ', this.currentUser) // Shows correct new user data
    }.bind(this))
    console.log('User outside eventbus:', this.currentUser) // Shows empty user
}
```

And this is how the user looks like in the data:

```
data: function () {
  return {
     currentUser: {
     firstname: '',
     lastname: '',
     last_login: ''
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out why the currentUser is emptied outside the eventbus. Thanks in advance!

**Edit: **
[This is how I have it now in my index.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdAf3.png)

**Edit 2: **
[This shows the output of the console logs. The left one shows the user object in the eventBus, the right one shows the `console.log(this)` outside the eventBus, with empty `currentUser` object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdes3.png)

This is the `$emit` of the eventBus, this is being called when the get request response is successfull. The code is in the `login.vue`, where an authenticated user object gets filled, and transfers this data to the `index.vue`.

`eventBus.$emit('thisEvent', {
        user: this.user
     })`

Comment: The code in question should work fine, the problem seems to be somewhere else. Can you post the whole code on jsfiddle?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal I have edited the post and added a screenshot, hope this makes it more clear!

Comment: Could you please add the console screenshots as well?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal added the other screenshot!

Comment: So the first `console.log(this)` (inside the `eventBus.on`) didnt print anything ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot add a new screenshot because I have too little reputation, but it showed almost the same result as the other one, except the user is filled with the data

Comment: That should be enough. Let me see. I am sorry, Another small request, please post eventBus code as well (not as screenshot) where the event is being emitted.

Comment: No problem, I have added the eventBus emit code.

Comment: are you doing the `$emit` in a watch?

Comment: No I have it in a `login function ()` within the `methods`. Do you think this has any effect? I personally am not too sure because the correct data is being received in the `index.vue`..

Comment: I hate myself for not figuring this out 2 hours ago, please look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an arrow function would help you as it doesn't bind its own context.

```
mounted: function () {
  eventBus.$on('thisEvent', (userObject) => {
    console.log('event received!', userObject)
    this.currentUser = userObject.user
    console.log('The user: ', this.currentUser)
  })
  console.log('User outside eventbus:', this.currentUser)
}
```

another way: (If you're not using `babel` or want to support browsers without ES6 support)

```
mounted: function () {
  var self = this
  eventBus.$on('thisEvent', function (userObject) {
    console.log('event received!', userObject)
    self.currentUser = userObject.user
    console.log('The user: ', self.currentUser)
  })
  console.log('User outside eventbus:', self.currentUser)
}
```

**EDIT**

The code in the question and the solutions posted in the thread work just fine. The output that you see is perfectly normal.

```
mounted: function () {
  eventBus.$on('thisEvent', function (userObject) {
    console.log('event received!', userObject)
    this.currentUser = userObject.user
    console.log('The user: ', this.currentUser) // Shows correct new user data
  }.bind(this))
  console.log('User outside eventbus:', this.currentUser) // Shows empty user
}
```

The `mounted` [lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) hook is called when the component's template and data is ready and rendered.

(You could do the same thing in the `created` hook as what you have done in `mounted`)

So

```
console.log('User outside eventbus:', this.currentUser)
```

gets logged before your `eventBus` emits an event.

you can easily check this using a `watch` like so:

```
watch: {
  currentUser(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue, oldValue)
  }
}
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjvMp/1186/)

Comment: Well there are no need for self since you are using let keyoword which also part of ECMAScript 6 specifications, as arrows functions are as well ;)

Comment: I'll remove `let` I just want to add the list of ways in which this can be done :) thanks.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is totally good, I just wanted to point out that - If OP doesn't use Babel but wants to support older browsers.

Comment: @BelminBedak I'll add that above that part of answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried your solution but somehow the user is still empty..

Comment: @EleinaNieborg can you `console.log(this)` or `console.log(self)` above both the console statements?

Comment: Amresh - Your answer is just duplicate of my answer just posted 3 minutes later.

Comment: I think arguing about that would be counter-productive, my edit is 14 minutes ago as of now, yours is 2 minutes ago. If you refer to the comments you would so find that my second solution was there long before you added. So please refrain from making such comments.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal, I have put both `console.log(this)`s like you said, and the one in the eventBus shows currentUser with the data, and the other one shows a currentUser without the data.. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @EleinaNieborg yes, that's what I meant. I wish to know what are the values you are observing, also did you try both the solutions? is there any error in the console?

Comment: Thank you so much for your edited answer! It really makes me understand the `mounted` life cycle better. But how can I give the data from the bus to the user object? It is still not possible to call e.g. `currentUser.firstname`, as it is empty..

Comment: @EleinaNieborg you just don't see it in the `mounted` lifecycle, it is there and accessible. Events are asynchronous, so the last `console.log` where you are expecting user data is not having it as the event which should bring it hasn't yet fulfilled. Add the `watch` part in your code you will see the difference.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal thank you very much for your help, I've got it working after having a closer look at your jsFiddle! Have marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot figure out why the currentUser is emptied outside the
>   eventbus.

Because of the `this` scope. Inside classic function syntax you are binding `this` from function. Use arrow function shown below and it will work as it does not bind `this` so `this.currentUser` will update your component data, not just function data.

```
mounted: function () {
    eventBus.$on('thisEvent', (userObject) => {
        console.log('event received!', userObject)
        this.currentUser = userObject.user
        console.log('The user: ', this.currentUser) // Shows correct new user data
    })
    console.log('User outside eventbus:', this.currentUser) // Shows empty user
}
```

If above somehow not working, try this solution:

```
mounted: function () {
        let _self = this;
        eventBus.$on('thisEvent', (userObject) => {
            console.log('event received!', userObject)
            _self.currentUser = userObject.user
            console.log('The user: ', _self.currentUser) // Shows correct new user data
        })
        console.log('User outside eventbus:', _self.currentUser) // Shows empty user
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `bind`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have also tried your solution but somehow the user is still empty..

Comment: @EleinaNieborg you could try with the storing vue instance into the variable, something like this `var vm = new Vue({// other code...})`, and then you can acess user by typing `vm.currentUser` - that should be pointet to correct context

Comment: Eleina it is really impossible. Please try to show us your code by JSFiddle or Webpack bin.  Did you remove `bind(this)` ?

Comment: Please look for typos etc. This code should work straight forward

Comment: @MU, I have searched for any typos, but cannot find one (unfortunately). I can provide you a screenshot, is this acceptable? Not really sure how to create it in JSFiddle..

Comment: yes, provide screenshot at least. Try to create JSFiffle/Webpack bin(if you are using *.vue files) later